# Checking status of lauterbach window command line

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

We use Perl script to launch a trace32 window on a remote machine and perform some operation, obviously the Perl cannot print any logs from trace32 window as its a separate GUI, very rarely the script fails probably because the trace32 failed, but there is no way to check in Perl script log about the trace32 failure, is there a command line option available to fetch the status or the error message printed in trace32 window ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late now, but for others looking for the same answer, what I did was save the B::area window log into a file and regex that file to my heart's content.

Here's a sample command to do it:

```
Prt.file C:\some\path\log.txt
winprint.area A000
prt.file
```

This can be done to any window area, by default the B::area window name is A000 that i know of.

Answer (score 0):

Area.View is the command to view the status messages and various operations performed during debugging on trace32. When the command is run, trace32 displays an window named "B::area.view".The contents of window can be saved to a text file and later parsed to check the error using perl. Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 0):

The default location for printing error or status messages is the AREA window with the ID "A000".
TRACE32 has commands for logging its contents to a file:

```
AREA.OPEN  A000 protocol.lst  ; area will be saved in 'protocol.lst'
DO test
...
AREA.CLOSE A000               ; all messages will be saved
```

`AREA.OPEN <id_area> <file>` opens a file for logging and directs all messages to be printed in the selected AREA window to it.

`AREA.CLOSE <id_area>` stops the logging.

Please refer to the file [ide_ref.pdf](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_ref.pdf) for a detailed description of these commands.